# How to draw arrow on the endpoint of GMSPolyline in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google Map iOS sdk. I added polyline on my google map using the following code. But now I want add arrow at the end of this line. How to solve this issue?

```
GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
[path addLatitude:-37.81319 longitude:144.96298];
[path addLatitude:-31.95285 longitude:115.85734];
GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
polyline.strokeWidth = 3.f;
polyline.map = mapaView;
```

[image: polyline must be look like this image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GMSMarker` to indicate endpoint of your polyline:

```
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.200000, 114.1333900);
    marker.title = @"Endpoint";
    marker.map = mapView;
```

Comment: I want to draw polyline like the above image

Comment: As per my understanding we can not achieve it using google API. But we can customise it using arrow image and its direction.